# How to add initial nominators in the customSpec.json?

Tags: genesis, substrate-node

I want to generate a `customSpec.json` where i can manually add the accounts of the `initial_nominators`. I've seen the code [chain_spec.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs) where we in the [fn testnet_genesis](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L242) there is initial nominators. How can we add this in `customSpec.json`?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `CustomSpec`

Answer (score 3):

This is where you should start reading:

https://docs.substrate.io/build/chain-spec/

You have already found chain_spec.rs where there are a few functions
`staging_testnet_config_genesis` and `local_testnet_config` cosponsoring to the different chains defined as names like `dev` `local` or `staging` [(defined in command.rs)](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e434882d5dbf3f3f6085cb7f1d017dbc4ac11f0a/bin/node/cli/src/command.rs#L66).

At [line 242](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L242) the vector `initial_nominators` is defined and at [line 384](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L384)  it is called with an empty argument, fill this vector with something like
`vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Bob")]` to get some initial nominators.

Then compile and run your node with argument `--chain=staging` and save the output generated chainspec.

Comment: I already know this thing. Can you please tell me How can i add nominators account in customSpec?

Comment: You add the accounts in the chain_spec.rs and compile the code. Then you use the correct chain (the one you changed) to generate the json chain-spec

Comment: @ArunjotSingh aha I see did my edit answer your question?